# Jetpack compose slowly loading Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen

I am trying simple navigation between composables and i noticed a performance issue during launch of the MainActivity , i am using splashScreen api for splash screen and then setting the content

```
 installSplashScreen()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        MyTheme {
            Navigation()
        }
    }
```

the issue is after the splashscreen and before my First composable showing there's an empty screen for a second , i tried to remove the Navigation and tried my composableScreen directly and it works fine, no empty black screen in between
this is my navigation composable

```
  @Composable
fun Navigation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = ScreenRoutes.Ls.route,
) {
    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable(route = ScreenRoutes.Ls.route) {
            Ls() { destination ->
                when (destination) {
                    ScreenRoutes.Ms-> {
                        navController.navigate(destination.route) {
                            popUpTo(0)
                        }
                    }
                    ScreenRoutes.Fp-> {
                        navController.navigate(destination.route)
                    }
                    ScreenRoutes.Ls-> {}
                    ScreenRoutes.Sc-> {
                        navController.navigate(destination.route)
                    }
                    ScreenRoutes.Up -> navController.navigateUp()
                }
            }
        }

        composable(route = ScreenRoutes.Sc.route) {
            Sc() { destination ->
                if (destination == ScreenRoutes.Up && navController.previousBackStackEntry != null) {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                } else {
                    navController.navigate(destination.route) {
                        popUpTo(0)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        composable(route = ScreenRoutes.Ms.route) {
            Ms() {

            }
        }

        composable(route = ScreenRoutes.fg.route) {
            ForgotPassword() { destination ->
                if (destination == ScreenRoutes.Up && navController.previousBackStackEntry != null) {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                } else {
                    navController.navigate(destination.route)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there any possible optimization , or making the splash to not be removed until the completion of composition,
i tried with release variant since it have minify is enabled and proguard , and it's showed slightly better results but the intermediate empty screen still exists

Comment: is this happening in emulator and a real device ?

Comment: in both , but much more severe in the emulator, my real device is a pixel 3A

Answer (score 0):

Does the issue persist on a real phone and emulator? If it is only on the emulator, it could be that your hardware can't keep up with your work.

Comment: it is less apparent in the real device,